# Should user input be able to cause an unhandled exception?

Tags: 7, security

Drupal 7's user login form (and I dare say others) can be tampered with client-side, to cause Drupal to throw an unhandled exception.

All you need to do is change the input fields, appending `[]` to the name of the name field, and Drupal will create invalid SQL and throw that at the database.

Is this considered a problem? Surely it's Drupal's job to ensure user input is sanitised to the point that it won't generate invalid SQL - is it a DOS risk/security issue?

e.g. Visit drupal.org's login page. Open firebug. Change the `<input name="name".../>` to `<input name="name[]" .../>` and add another one just like it. Put some values in both name fields and the password and submit. You get the "This website has encountered an error." page of death.

(I can vouch for this under Drupal 7.35, and on drupal.org which I presume is 7.36)

[image: screenshot from drupal.org]

...

[image: screenshot 2 from drupal.org]

Comment: Can you give some examples of these queries? I'm going to assume they're related to esoteric character sets? You need to remember that Drupal uses PDO - so at best, it's PDO's job to ensure user input is sanitised

Comment: Edited question. This is to do with Drupal accepting an array where it should require a string, so it's generating SQL like "WHERE user = :user_0, :user_1". (so passing invalid SQL to PDO).

Comment: If it's passing invalid SQL to PDO then yes, definitely a bug. Are you sure it definitely is, though? i.e. are you sure that PDO isn't expanding the arguments, and that Drupal is? Have you confirmed that the invalid SQL query is actually being run on the server, and that the fatal error doesn't come from a point in code _before_ the query is run?

Comment: Yep I'm sure. I've seen the SQL issued (PDO does not expand array params, that's one of the things Drupal's API does).

Comment: I've edited the input name and pass iin a Drupal 7 fresh installation adding [] to the name of each elem and I only get some PHP warnings (mb_sterlen and addcslashes functions expect string insted of array) but no blank page of death.

Comment: Same as what @tunic says - I can't reproduce this. Perhaps you have a version of Drupal older than 7.32 (when code surrounding arrays in queries was changed), your error reporting is set too high, or something else? It may still be a bug, or at least undesirable behaviour, but it's not a security threat. The query is still parametised, the syntax is just invalid

Comment: Put visual proof in question. But I agree that it's still parametised. Still doesn't look right to me, though. So if you want to post an answer "yes, Drupal does not consider it bad practise to allow user input to cause an unhandled exception to be thrown" then I'll accept. - It's fair enough, we are talking about malicious intent - why should they get a pretty error? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, user input shoulnd't cause and unhandled exception. Not only because is a nasty reponse form server but it reveals an error condition not handled so it may head to security issues. A non-handled error means that developers are not aware of that error (or they are too lazy, what may be worst).

All error conditions should be handled to minimize problems related to that uncontrolled error.

I've tried to reproduce the bug (with two input name fields with `name="name[]"` as you have shown in your images) without getting reported error. So I think this
particular case you mention seems to be a drupal.org bug or a module bug of a module used in the Drupal site. You can report the bug in the [Drupal.org infrastructure issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/infrastructure?categories=1)

Comment: Weird you can't reproduce. I've tried three sites and they all behave the same (admittedly not a fresh install). FWIW, the  reason I'm looking into this is that I have detected several malicious attack attempts on one of my sites using this method. I presume they're trying to probe for the drupalgeddon thing (which I patched for ages ago).

Comment: I have caught an exploit attempt from the wild that is an example and saved the `_POST` data. Should I post it here or would that be considered bad security practise?

Comment: If you think you have found a security issue you can find instructions to report it here: https://www.drupal.org/node/101494 In short you have to goto he project page of the component affected and follow the "Report a security vulnerability" link. Exploits should be not published until a component is patched for security reasons.

Comment: It's basically the drupageddon thing. They fixed the security side because an uncaught exception is not considered a security risk. I guess it's an infrastructure queue thing.